# while using tensorflow i got errer : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, string, integer, nonetype

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

data_path = 'C:/Users/jeado/Desktop/Facial-Recognition-master/faces'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path,f))]

Training_Data, Labels = [], []

for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
    image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]
    images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
    Labels.append(i)

Labels = np.asarray(Labels, dtype=np.int32)

model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

model.train(np.asarray(Training_Data), np.asarray(Labels))

model.write('LBPHFaceRecognizer.xml')

print("Model Training Complete!!!!!")
```

#but error exists
#File "C:\Users\jeado\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

#TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

how to solve ? please help me

Comment: could you specify more at which line does error occur?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code that it doesn't read files from directory,
if the path is data_path  is `'C:/Users/jeado/Desktop/Facial-Recognition-master/faces'`
and there is a file called `'hello.png'`

when you execute  `image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]`
the resultant path is `'C:/Users/jeado/Desktop/Facial-Recognition-master/faceshello.png'`
to solve that

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

data_path = 'C:/Users/jeado/Desktop/Facial-Recognition-master/faces'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path,f))]

Training_Data, Labels = [], []

for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
    image_path = join(data_path ,onlyfiles[i])
    images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
    Labels.append(i)

Labels = np.asarray(Labels, dtype=np.int32)

model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

model.train(np.asarray(Training_Data), np.asarray(Labels))

model.write('LBPHFaceRecognizer.xml')

print("Model Training Complete!!!!!")
```